# Casting structs with non-aggregate members

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I am receiving an segmentation fault (SIGSEGV) when I try to reinterpret_cast a struct that contains an vector. The following code does not make sense on its own, but shows an minimal working (failing) example.

```
// compiler: g++ -std=c++17
struct Table
{
     std::vector<int> ids;
};

std::vector<std::byte> storage;

// put that table into the storage
Table table = {.ids = {3, 5}};
auto convert = [](Table x){ return reinterpret_cast<std::byte*>(&x); };
std::byte* bytes = convert(table);
storage.insert(storage.end(), bytes, bytes + sizeof(Table));

// ...

// get that table back from the storage
Table& tableau = *reinterpret_cast<Table*>(&storage.front());
assert(tableau.ids[0] == 3);
assert(tableau.ids[1] == 5);
```

The code works fine if I inline the convert function, so my guess is that some underlying memory is deleted. The convert function makes a local copy of the table and after leaving the function, the destructor for the local copy's ids vector is called. Recasting just
returns the vector, but the ids are already deleted.

So here are my questions:

1. Why does the segmentation fault happen? (Is my guess correct?)
2. How could I resolve this issue?

Thanks in advance :D

Comment: You are attempting to copy a `Table` by simply copying the bytes of the object.  Since `Table` is **not** [Trivially Copyable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/TriviallyCopyable) this is Undefined Behavior.  This is not how arbitrary objects are copied, since it bypasses whatever the copy constructor does.

Comment: You likely want to reinterpret `ids.data()` as your `byte*`.  Generally speaking the vector stores its data on the heap so you'll likely find only the pointer to the data within the object itself.  (exceptions for implementations that optimize for very small amounts of data notwithstanding)

Comment: To answer _"how could I resolve this issue?"_ look into [Object Serialization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization). Beyond that, any more detailed advice might be highly dependent on your precise goals. It could be you're going about solving (whatever actual requirements are) entirely backwards. Or not. We have no way of knowing.

Comment: I just wanted to store multiple vectors of different types in the same container. So in the example, storage ist just one of many vectors. I do not know the types in advance, so using ```ids.data()``` is probably not possible. So my idea was to just save byte arrays and let the caller decide the types using templates.

Comment: Usually, using `reinterpret_cast` is a red flag and should be avoided unless you have to... If you want to serialize binary data, I would recommand to use some library that was written to be portable and versionnable... Also, you might consider using text format (either json or xml) instead of binary data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I see at least three reasons for undefined behavior in the shown code, that fatally undermines what the shown code is attempting to do. One or some combination of the following reasons is responsible for your observed crash.

```
struct Table
{
     std::vector<int> ids;
};
```

Reason number 1 is that this is not a trivially copyable object, so any attempt to copy it byte by byte, as the shown code attempts to do, results in undefined behavior.

```
storage.insert(storage.end(), bytes, bytes + sizeof(Table));
```

Reason number 2 is that `sizeof()` is a ***compile*** time constant. You might be unaware that the `sizeof` of this `Table` object is always the same, whether or not its vector is empty or contains the first billion digits of π. The attempt here to copy the whole object into the byte buffer, this way, therefore fails for this fundamental reason.

```
auto convert = [](Table x){ return reinterpret_cast<std::byte*>(&x); };
```

Reason number 3 is that this lambda, for all practical purposes, is the same as any other function with respect to its parameters: its `x` parameter goes out of scope and gets destroyed as soon as this function returns.

When a function receives a parameter, that parameter is just like a local object in the function, and is a copy of whatever the caller passed to it, and like all other local objects in the function it gets destroyed when the function returns. This function ends up returning a pointer to a destroyed object, and subsequent usage of this pointer also becomes undefined behavior.

In summary, what the shown code is attempting to do is, unfortunately, going against multiple core fundamentals of C++, and manifests in a crash for one or some combination of these reasons; C++ simply does not work this way.

> The code works fine if I inline the convert function

If, by trial and error, you come up with some combination of compiler options, or cosmetic tweaks, that avoids a crash, for some miraculous reason, it doesn't fix any of the underlying problems and, at some point later down the road you'll get a crash anyway, or the code will fail to work correctly. Guaranteed.

> How could I resolve this issue?

The only way for you to resolve this issue is, well, not do any of this. You also indicated that what you're trying to do is just "store multiple vectors of different types in the same container". This happens to be what [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) can easily handle, safely, so you'll want to look into that.